# USB connects then disconnects on QEMU / windows 10 guest

Tags: arch-linux, windows, qemu, spice

Essentially the usb device connects for about 2-3 seconds, then disconnects for about 2-3 seconds, then reconnects... This also happens if I pass it through directly. If I install the spice-tools the mouse disappears, but even then the USB doesn't work. The error is the same but not exactly the same behavior as [this](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/spice/usbredir/-/issues/5); i.e. `LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND`

Notably, I'm using an nvidia 1060 and applied [this](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/nvidia-gpu-passthrough-with-virtual-machine-manager-how-to-fix-error-43/162250) because the normal method doesn't work.

I am currently using a spice display in conjunction with direct 1060 output as that way I can more easily share my keyboard / mouse. When using an AMD card this wasn't an issue.

Also, for some reason at random times the sound gets super staticky, and this seems to also sometimes be triggered by plugging in a usb. Notably, this stops happening if I use an LVN screen instead of spice.

Kernel: 5.9.16-1-MANJARO
libvirtd: 6.5.0
QEMU emulator: 5.2.0

Alternatively, is there a way to pass through USBs using the LVN screen?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not a solution but a workaround that I've repeated several times...

1. Have a USB spice redirector in QEMU manager
2. when the windows 10 boots go to device manager
3. unplug and replug your USB device (mine is an xbox one controller)
4. when the cycling begins and the first cycle hits (it shows up as connected) quickly restart the windows VM
5. on reboot the USB device will either be recognized or it will cycle a few times then settle down to be recognized.

If it's cycling when you get back in you may need to restart again / your timing was bad. I think this "solution" also requires patience, lol.

You will likely have to do this everytime this issue is occuring and I don't know if it works for multiple devices at once or anything but the xbox controller. I will update if a better solution is found.